# Matching until first occurrence of a term followed by a character

Tags: regex

I would like match the string that only has one search term (that would only be the first string in my example). Strings with multiple search terms are separated by a `+` sign:

- `jobs?search=term1&location=&distance=10+page=2`
- `jobs?search=term1+term2&location=ca&distance=30`
- `jobs?search=term1+term2+term3&location=nyc&distance=25`

My idea was to match any word (preceded by `search=`) *not* followed by `+` but *is* followed with `&`:

`search=.*?[^+]&`

But it doesn't quite work and captures strings with multiple terms.

Comment: Could you please let us know what the programming language is it for?

Comment: I'd like to use it in Python or R.

Comment: Oh, in R it will be a bit clumsy unless you want to use `stringr` package. I will add example code then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
[&?]search=([^&+]+)(?=&|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jp9ZlZ/1)

It will match:

- `[&?]` - a `?` or `&` (to make sure `search` is the  whole key name)
- `search=` - a literal substring
- `([^&+]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ symbols other than `+` and `&`
- `(?=&|$)` - a lookahead requiring a `&` or end of string to appear immediately after the last symbol captured with the preceding subpattern (note it can be replaced with a non-capturing group, `(?:&|$)`, the value will be still in Group 1).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Y06YQ7):

```
import re
ss = ['jobs?search=term1&location=&distance=10+page=2','jobs?search=term1+term2&location=ca&distance=30','jobs?search=term1+term2+term3&location=nyc&distance=25']
rx = re.compile(r'[&?]search=([^&+]+)(?=&|$)')
for s in ss:
    m = rx.search(s)
    if m:
        print("{}: {}".format(s, m.group(1)))
```

[Base R](https://ideone.com/rbYKSS):

```
ss <- c('jobs?search=term1&location=&distance=10+page=2','jobs?search=term1+term2&location=ca&distance=30','jobs?search=term1+term2+term3&location=nyc&distance=25')
results <- regmatches(ss, regexec("[&?]search=([^&+]+)(?:&|$)",ss))
unlist(results)[2]
```

... or with R *stringr*:

```
> library(stringr)
> ss <- c('jobs?search=term1&location=&distance=10+page=2','jobs?search=term1+term2&location=ca&distance=30','jobs?search=term1+term2+term3&location=nyc&distance=25')
> results <- str_match(ss, "[&?]search=([^&+]+)(?:&|$)")
> results[,2]
[1] "term1" NA      NA     
>
```

Comment: Maybe you should cut the [&?] part at the beginning of the regex ?

Comment: @Gawil: What do you mean by "cut" here? Remove? But `search` must be matched as a param key. I would keep it for safer matching.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Yeah i meant remove. I understand the safe matching... but OP didn't want the ? to match so... Maybe with a lookbehind, depending on the language ?

Comment: Any solution involving a lookbehind is losing in performance. Look at degant's answer. [370 steps](https://regex101.com/r/pRYdI8/2/) vs. [my 213](https://regex101.com/r/pRYdI8/1). I understand that is not a proof that performance differ greatly here, but still, almost 2 times as more steps. And that is also because he is not using lazy matching appropriately.

Comment: That is exactly why I did propose to cut the [&?] and not to use a lookbehind (you just wanted a safe match). I think the strings OP uses are specific enough not to find the term "search=" before the real ketword.

Comment: @Gawil: Better safe than sorry. What if the input is `jobs?locationsearch=place1&distance=10+page=2&search=term0+term1`? It should not match.

Comment: I don't know, this is a problem only apples-oranges can solve ^^ Just pointing out that your regex might not match the exact substring OP wants.

Comment: @Gawil: It is not important what you match in this case, only what you *capture* matters.

Comment: This is excellent! Thanks again for providing such a clear answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only capture the term and not the preceding `search=`:

```
(?<=search=)[^+]*?(?=&|$)
```

- `(?<=search=)` - Positive Lookbehind to ensure the search= precedes the term
- `[^+]*?` - To match the term (makes sure it doesn't include any +). This is a non-greedy match (using `*?`) so that the first occurrence of & works
- `(?=&|$)` - Positive Lookahead to ensure the term is followed by either a `&` or end of string (`$`)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nA3chX/2)